# Python Dictionary: move values based on key

Tags: python

In my code, I am trying to see if a key has a certain name(like phone_work), and if it does, append that key's values to another key (like phone_home). Right now, I get an attributeError message as describe in a comment in my code below. I just started learning Python last week, so I may just be making an easy mistake, but if anyone can educate me on the mistake I am making, it would be greatly appreciated :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys #used for passing in the argument. The file
import csv, glob

fieldMap = {'zipcode':['Zip5', 'zip4'],
        'firstname':[],
        'lastname':[],
        'cust_no':[],
        'user_name':[],
        'status':[],
        'cancel_date':[],
        'reject_date':[],
        'streetaddr':['address2', 'servaddr'],
        'city':[],
        'state':[],
        'phone_home':['phone_work'],
        'email':[]
        }

CSVreader = csv.DictReader(open( 'N:/Individual Files/Jerry/2013 customer list qc, cr, db, gb 9-19-2013_JerrysMessingWithVersion.csv', "rb"),dialect='excel', delimiter=',')

CSVreader.has_key('phone.+') #AttributeError: DictReader instance has no attribute 'has_key'

if true:
    SLSDictionary['phone_home'].append([value])
```

Comment: Probably because a DictReader is not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#reader-objects) object is not the same as a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). You cannot access the "key" of a `DictReader` because it doesn't expose any - you need to iterate the rows within the reader, and *those* will have keys mapped to the column names because each row will be represented as a dictionary.

E.g. you would do something like this (using [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement), which is the best practice):

```
with open('yourFile', 'rb') as f:
    CSVReader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')

    for row in CSVReader:
        if row.has_key('yourKey'):
            #Do something with the row
```

You may also want to include appropriate error handling while iterating, such as:

```
with open('yourFile', 'rb') as f:
    CSVReader = csv.DictReader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter=',')

    for row in CSVReader:
        try:
            if row.has_key('yourKey'):
                #Do something with the row
        except csv.Error as e
            #Handle or report the exception
```

The [examples section](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html#examples) of the csv module's documentation has some other sample code that may be of use.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I didn't know DictReader wouldn't treat it as a dictionary. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: and you explained it so well, and I'm going over the documentation now! thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is that you're not actually testing the value in your if clause.

You should be doing:

```
if CSVreader.has_key('phone.+'):
    SLSDictionary['phone_home'].append([value])
```

Otherwise you will execute the if clause every time. With python, you have if (boolean):, and since your boolean is just "true", the if will always evaluate.

Comment: That will raise the same `AttributeError` that the OP's code is raising.

Comment: Ah, true. I guess he should be using has_key on the dictionary?

Comment: Hey everyone, I think I'm gonna use a for loop without a has_key and see how that works, and thanks for the input